# In general, at the Master level, is the concentration Applied Maths easier/more practical than other branches of “Pure Maths”?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics, masters, education

I'm choosing the direction for my graduate study. I like Maths, but have limited exposure to different areas of it. As I've only just finished my Bachelor, I can't say for sure what my strengths are, or what my direction would be after graduate school. However, I don't think I want to do research in the long terms, at least not in an Universities. A technical role in the industry is more appealing to me at the moment.

I'm planning to do my Master in Europe, most likely Germany.

Also by "Pure Maths" I mean areas like Topology, Algebra, Geometry, Combinatorics, etc.

I'm aware that all areas have their own difficult unsolved problems and are comprised of both theory and practical applications. I'm just asking about this issue as strictly applied to graduate-level taught programs.

Comment: The question in the title's a bit confusing; being "_more practical_" and "_easier_" seem to be divergent qualifications.  Do you mean you're looking for a subfield of Math that's maximally practical for a given amount of effort invested into it?  And if so, what's the basis for practicality; usefulness in the job market?

Comment: Do you want to do stuff that's easy, or do you want to do stuff that interests you? In any case the two are very connected. I wasn't interested by applied math, and the few courses I took that leaned more on the applied side were harder for me. For other people it's the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are more industry jobs for Masters in applied math than for other branches.  My Ph.D. school produced a certain number of MS in applied math.  For some reason Pilsbury hired a lot of them.  In pure math, a wise professor told me, "If you don't have your Ph.D., you ain't shit."  Putting these data points together, I think you'll find that if you're going to stop at a Masters degree, then applied math is the most practical.